# Unable to remove row spacing in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Grid and showing couple of grid items there. My problem is there are lots of rowSpacing between rows in Grid. I have removed VerticalOptions from the StackLayout. RowSpacing is only showing for Android. In iOS it works perfectly. Here is snippet. Can anyone let me know what's wrong with my code.

Here is XAML file

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Monekto.Views.Enjoy.EnjoyOfferLatest">
    <ContentView.Content>

          <!-- Main View -->
        <StackLayout 
            Spacing = "0"
            Margin = "0"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="White">

            <ScrollView Orientation = "Vertical">

            <!-- Grid layout -->
             <Grid 
                Padding="5" 
                RowSpacing = "0"
                HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Row = "0"
                    Grid.Column = "0"
                    Spacing = "0"
                    HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                    >

                    <Image
                        Source = "latest_one.png"
                        HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                        />

                    <Label 
                        Text = "Mothercare today"
                        FontSize= "15"
                        Margin = "0"
                        HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand">
                    </Label>

                     <Label 
                        Text = "www.google.com"
                        FontSize= "10"
                        Margin = "0"
                        HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand">
                    </Label>


                </StackLayout>

                 <StackLayout
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Grid.Row = "0"
                        Grid.Column = "1"
                        Spacing = "0"
                        HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                        >

                        <Image
                            Source = "latest_one.png"
                            HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                           />

                        <Label 
                            Text = "Mothercare today"
                            Margin = "0"
                            FontSize= "15"
                            HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand">
                        </Label>

                        <Label 
                            Text = "www.google.com"
                            FontSize= "10"
                            Margin = "0"
                            HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand">
                        </Label>

                    </StackLayout>
                  </Grid>

             </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

P.S : I have four rows but in snippet I only include first row. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't see any row spacing when testing with your code , and the test result was same on Android and iOS. Could you upload a illustration to describe it?

Comment: I am wondering how it is working in your end. I don't have code right now. I will upload image soon. @ColeXia